# Not generating swagger document - Node JS + swaggerJSDoc

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-jsdocs

I am trying to crate swagger documentation for my Node JS express APIs. Added following code in app.js:

```
const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0', // Specification (optional, defaults to swagger: '2.0')
    info: {
      title: 'Hello World!', // Title (required)
      version: '1.0.0', // Version (required)
    },
  },
  // Path to the API docs
  apis: ['routes/*.js']
};
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);
// console.log(swaggerSpec)
app.get('/api-docs.json', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(swaggerSpec);
});
app.use('/api/docs',express.static('./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist'));
```

In one of routes of application added following documentation:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * resourcePath: /api
 * /login:
 *   post:
 *     description: Login to the application
 *     produces:
 *       - application/json
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: username
 *         description: Username to use for login.
 *         in: formData
 *         required: true
 *         type: string
 *       - name: password
 *         description: User's password.
 *         in: formData
 *         required: true
 *         type: string
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: login
 */
```

Following output is generated while accessing http://localhost:4000/api-docs.json

```
{"openapi":"3.0.0","info":{"title":"Hello World!","version":"1.0.0"},"paths":{},"components":{},"tags":[]}
```

However actual documentation is not generated. Any help in fixing this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to use [Swagger UI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui), [Swagger UI Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the problem and its solution.

Path of apis property has to be relative path from root Modified  `apis: ['routes/*.js']` to `apis: ["src/routers/*.js"]` and it worked.